# Single host Windows and MacOS software inventory / asset management software

Tags: inventory

I'm looking for software to generate a list of installed applications on Windows and MacOS systems, including version and licence information.

There's loads of options available but all seem to use a client / server system to scan an entire network of systems and generate a single huge report.

What I need is an application that a copy of could be sent to a remote worker not connected to the network and they run it locally to generate a software information list. Does anything like that exist?

Comment: I know a solution for Windows. 10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer can collect the data in the way you are describing. The client app can be started by a remote worker, collect the data locally, and save it to a file. These files should be imported to the main program so it will form a common inventory database allowing you to create reports on separate machines or all together (software, hardware, licenses...) It also tracks changes (on repeated scans) and displays or sends it to you via email. Unfortunately, they do not have this client app for Mac. MacOS can be scanned only via remote SSH.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy, appreciate the recommendation